# Magento Custom theme template file is not calling

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I create a new theme in magento like below
Namespace : ndot , Template : english, then in admin configuration i defined this is my theme.

Copy the layout files form **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout** to  **app/design/frontend/ndot/english/layout**.
template files
**app/design/frontend/base/default/template** to 
app/design/frontend/ndot/english/template/customer.

but when i changes the file in app/design/frontend/ndot/english/template/customer/form/register.phtml, the changes is never reflecting

How to i fix this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Is the cache is disable? Enable path hind and check the files is rendered from your theme or base.

Comment: the cache is enable stage. the ndot/layout files is rendering, if i hide the block in site <customer_account_create> the block is not showing, but only the template file is not rendered.

Comment: Disable the cache and try again. If you not getting after disable the cache, delete the var/cache folder

Comment: i disabled the cache and deleted the files/folder inside the var/cache , still my new theme register.phtml fils is not get call.

Comment: Have place the register.phtml file in correct path. `app/design/frontend/ndot/english/template`

Comment: its place in app/design/frontend/ndot/english/template/customer/form/register.phtml, and attached the design settings screen in my question for your further  referrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have edited in wrong file.
Customer register form file is render from the following path

`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

So try to copy this folder path and file in your theme and check.

Comment: i think rwd is namespace, the rwd folder is not is mgento default.

Comment: If your magento version is 1.9 you have the red namespace. Or else you don't have that.  Just copy the persistent/customer/form/register.phtml in you folder. Then edit the file you get the changes in frontend

Comment: my version in 1.7, i did the changes is app/design/frontend/ndot/english/template/customer/account/dashboard.phtml , this changes is reflect, but the register.phtml changes is not reflect in frontend.

Comment: `/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` copy this file form base to your theme. Enable the path hint you can see the register.phtml file is not rendered from the ndot/English template/customer/form/register.phtml

Comment: thanks for your help. as per your point, the register.phtml and login.phtml files is get from persistent folder .